# Microservices communication for queries from front end UI

Tags: .net, microservices, cqrs

According to Microservices documentation, it is recommended not to communicate between microservices synchronously by request/response Http pattern unless it's required. I have questions on Microservices communication.

I have four microservices:

```
Catalog --> product information details
Pricing --> pricing details of products
Inventory --> product availability, in-stock or out of stock
Marketing --> notifying marketing team on searched product
```

I have an UI interface where user can search the product and on search of the product it would make http call onto catalog microservice to get the product details. Now at the same time while pulling product information to display on to the front end UI, I will also need Price of the product which is a pricing microservice and also Inventory Microservice to show if it's in-stock or out of stock on to the UI. Additionally I will have to notify marketing department about the product search.

My design here would be, after the UI search I would reach the API gateway making Http call to the Catalog Microservice and while getting details from Catalog I would make two different Http calls one for Pricing microservice and other for Inventory Microservice to get the details, after I got responses I would form the response DTO and pass it on to the front end UI to display details about product, Pricing, in-stock or out of stock. Meanwhile I am planning to put a message on to RabbitMQ for Marketing team to subscribe the message and use it for marketing purposes.

Now based on the Microservice design pattern it is recommended not to use Http request/response type of communication between microservices, but do I have an option here ? how else I can communicate between microservices to send response back to the front end UI with all the details about pricing, inventory along with Product information if I don't follow synchronous request/response http communication.

However in marketing microservice I am using asynchronous communication of consuming messages from RabbitMQ about item search and updating the Marketing database.

Any suggestions on the above communication, is there a better way of commination between microservices if the request from front end UI needs details from multiple microservices to show on UI.

Comment: I don't think that is a bad approach.  THere are many dimensions you can categorize api's across.  One such way may be the mecahnism: request / reply or response (think REST), asynch message passing (thinking Rabbit MQ) and actor based frameworks.  You might choose req/repl when you know what logic is next and where it is located, actor when you know what logic is next - but not necessarily where it is located, and asych message when you now neither next logic nor location (you essentially transition state).  I am certain there are other mechanisms (e.g. broadcast / fanning) but

Answer (score 2):

I've had the exact same doubts in an exact same context and there wasn't much to look for online.

Firstly, I've learned that there are cases that just wouldn't work using an async approach, and fetching products from a catalog is definitely one of them, since it could compromise user experience.

Having that said, you could of course use the API composition pattern which aggregates results from multiple services, but most of the api gateways frameworks/tools do not support aggregations for some reason, plus, that pattern has flaws when complex querying is needed.

I would maintain an aggregated service composed of the joined data you need when querying (possibly denormalized). Whenever the possessed data changes events are published and that new service would be updated accordingly.

By having a separate service for queries (basically implementing CQRS in some services), you wouldn't be compromising the "main" services by making them tightly coupled to other services/api gateway. Moreover, you would be segregating reads from write operations, which is always a good practice. Those aggregated services would be responsible for queries only, and with a single request, you could fetch data that is present in multiple services without having to ask them directly. Of course, further eventual consistency comes to the table, but CAP theorem.